# reactStringReplace() inconsistent regex match

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, match

I'm trying to use react-string-replace to match all $Symbols within a string of text.

Here are a few example values we'd like to be matched (stock / crypto / forex pairs): $GPRO, $AMBA, $BTC/USD, $LTC/ETH

Here is our attempted regex

```
/\$\S+[^\s]*/g
```

when passing the string

> $this works great $this/works great too.

through `.match()` - the proper symbols are returned in an array.

```
0: "$this"
1: "$this/works"
```

When using

reactStringReplace() - each match is returning

```
works great
```

Any ideas why

```
reactStringReplace()
```

seems to be handling this regex incorrectly?

Thanks ya'll!

Comment: Please show the actual code you're using. Ideally, create a [mcve]. Edit: added brackets to grab the match: https://codesandbox.io/s/6v9vorn33w

Comment: you know `\S` and `[^\s]` are the same right?

Comment: @chrisg much appreciated 

p.s. sorry about the lack of usable information, I will take that into account moving forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [*`React String Replace`* documentation](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace), it is written there:

> **`reactStringReplace(string, match, func)`**
>   ...
>   **match**
>   Type: `regexp|string`
>   
>   The string or RegExp you would like to replace within `string`. Note that when using a `RegExp` you **MUST** include a matching group.

**Why should you add a capturing group?** See the [`replaceString`](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace/blob/master/index.js#L30) function. There is `var result = str.split(re);` line that uses the pattern to actually ***split*** the contents you pass to the regex with your pattern thus *tokenizing* the whole input into parts that match and those that do not match your regex.

If you do not add a group to the regex passed as a *String*, the capturing parentheses will be [added automatically around the whole pattern](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace/blob/master/index.js#L42):

```
if (!isRegExp(re)) {
    re = new RegExp('(' + escapeRegExp(re) + ')', 'gi');
}
```

If you pass your regex as a *RegExp* without capturing parentheses, the matches will be missing from the resulting array, hence, they will disappear.

So, use

```
/(\$\S+)/g
```

If you want to keep the `$` chars in the output, or

```
/\$(\S+)/g
```

if you want to omit the dollars.